# List sort according to desired condition

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, arraylist

```
var non_community1 =new List<string>{ "red-11","red-10","red-9","orange-11","green-11","green-7","green-9", "green-9" ,"orange-9","green-11"};

non_community1 = non_community1.OrderByDescending(s => int.Parse(Regex.Match(s, @"\d+").Value)).ToList();

for (int i = non_community1.Count - 1; i > 0; i--) 
{
    if ((non_community1[i] == non_community1[i - 1]))
    {   
        non_community1.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

this code give me that to sort

[image: this code give me that to sort]

this is the list i want to produce

[image: this is the list i want to produce]

I'm a little stuck at this part, how do I get out of it?

I want to write the same at least 3 numbers in different color groups in sequence and I want to add "null" between the numbers that write 3 or more consecutive numbers.

Comment: you would need to explain a little more the thought behind the sorting.  Why would `red-10` be between 9 and 7 ? Especially if your algorithm aims directly for the integer?

Comment: okay , wait i explaned.

Comment: I want to write the same at least 3 numbers in different color groups in sequence and I want to add "null" between the numbers that write 3 or more consecutive numbers. @MongZhu

Comment: you should edit your question like your comment @stormingangel

Comment: "I want to write the same at least 3 numbers " then this should also be in your code. usually you would use `GroupBy` for this job and then sort according to occurences

Comment: @MongZhu I asked something down below so I tagged it, please don't be mad at me.

Comment: @stormingangel no worries, I am not mad. I was just a while not online. I wrote an answer to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so (after you removed the duplicates) you would need to use `GroupBy` to aggregate the items with the same integer and sort them according to their occurence:

```
var groupedResult = non_community1
                        .GroupBy( s => int.Parse(Regex.Match(s, @"\d+").Value))
                        .OrderByDescending(k => k.Count()).ToList();
```

Now you need to go through each group and collect them in the final list.

> and I want to add "null" between the numbers that write 3 or more consecutive numbers.

For this you can check how many items are in each group if you have more than 2 items then add the `null` item.

```
List<string> finalList = new List<string>();

for ( int i = 0; i < groupedResult.Count; i++ )
{
    finalList.AddRange(groupedResult[i]);
    if(groupedResult[i].Count() > 2)
    {
        finalList.Add(null);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, finalList));
```

and you should have your [desired result](https://dotnetfiddle.net/N4oRl4)

Comment: @stormingangel glad I could help. Welcome to StackOverflow. Next time try to provide all the requirements in the beginning ;)

Comment: heyy can i ask something about that questions?

Comment: It is not on this list at the moment, but it is available in single numbers. As you can see, there are 2 numbers. What you did was to separate the 3s, we added null between them. Well, in the rest of this code, if I want to put null between doubles and singles, is it enough to duplicate the if operation, I tried because it didn't work.

Comment: @stormingangel if you want to put a `null` between each group irrespective of the number of items you would need to remove the if-clause completely. The if clause filters all groups with more than 2 items, so 3 and more. Without the if-clause there is no discrimination